# "certains d'entre nous, dont moi" vs "certains d'entre nous, comme moi"

Tags: grammaire

> Certains d'entre nous, **dont moi**, avons choisi de ne pas faire ...
>
> {vs}: Certains d'entre nous, **comme moi**, avons choisi de ne pas faire ...

I can't shake off the feeling that something is off about the 2nd phrasing; perhaps, there is an  issue of the plural-singular mismatch between "certains" and "comme moi"? I wonder if "dont moi" should always be the one to use after "certains d'entre nous".

Answer (score 3):

Effectivement, la deuxième phrase est bizarre. Elle est compréhensible, mais elle est logiquement invalide en langage courant (même si elle est mathématiquement correcte), ce qui rend la compréhension plus difficile.

> Certains d'entre nous, dont moi, avons …

Le sujet est un sous-ensemble de « nous » et je fais partie de ce sous ensemble. Aucun problème.

> Certains d'entre nous, comme moi, avons …

« Certains d'entre nous » font la même chose que moi. En language courant, on ne peut pas dire que « je » fais « comme moi » : je *suis* moi. Donc « moi » ne fait pas partie de l'ensemble de personnes désigné par « certains d'entre nous ». Pourtant le verbe est à la première personne, donc « moi » fait partie de « certains d'entre nous ».

Le mot *comme* peut avoir le sens de « par exemple » mais ce n'est pas le sens qui vient à l'esprit dans cette phrase. « Moi » est un élément très particulier de « nous » ; si on veut le prendre comme exemple, il faudrait insister plus lourdement, mais on tournerait la phrase autrement.

Donc :

- « Certains d'entre nous avons … » — l'utilisation de la première personne implique que « je » est inclus.
- « Moi et d'autres avons … » est une autre manière de formuler la phrase de telle sorte qu'il n'est pas ambigu que « je » est inclus, mais sans insister.
- « Certains d'entre nous, dont moi, avons … » — insiste sur le fait que « je » est inclus.
- « Certains d'entre nous, dont notamment moi, avons … » — dit en plus qu'il est particulièrement remarquable que « je » soit inclus.

Si « je » était exclu, on ne dirait pas « certains d'entre nous », même si « <sup>?</sup> Certains d'entre nous, mais pas moi, ont … » est logiquement correct. On répèterait une désignation du groupe au lieu d'utiliser un pronom : « une partie de mon club d'échecs, mais pas moi, avons … ».

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd phrase is not wrong but sound bad. You should stick with :

> "Certains d'entre nous, **dont moi**, avons choisi de ne pas faire ..."

Or to answer your question, you could also use :

> "Certains d'entre nous, **moi compris**, avons choisi de ne pas faire ...

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are perfectly acceptable to all intents and purposes, and arguably convey the exact same meaning.

Compare 'Certains, comme moi, avons…' with English 'Some of us, like me, have…'

What might have bothered you in the first place is the agreement of the verb 'avons' with 'nous', which is obviously not the grammatical subject ('Certains' is). [Here is some account](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4819) on this usage.

An example of plural-singular mismatch in French usage would be 'un jeans', where there is an obvious discrepancy between the singular article and its (pseudo-)plural noun. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are fine.

In most circumstances, they would mean exactly the same thing. However, if you wanted to emphasize for some reason that those who chose not to do it shared some characteristics with you, you might prefer the second sentence.

I think this is analogous to what would happen in English if you had to choose between "some people, including me" and "some people, like me."

Comment: Actually, in English "like" could mean "including" here, too.

Comment: Yes, of course, I think you may be misunderstanding what I said. I said that in most cases they would mean exactly the same thing, i.e., "including." However, if a person wanted to emphasize shared characteristics, they would be likely to prefer "like."

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I got the sense that *comme* could not mean *y compris* in this context (unlike "like"), but I see that you're saying it could.